# Object that comes in Spring @RequestBody is not working

Tags: java, json, spring, set, hashset

I have an object that has a list of another object inside it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEDIDO")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6787191900085416567L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    private Date instante;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pedido")
    private Pagamento pagamento;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENTE_ID")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENDERECO_DE_ENTREGA_ID")
    private Endereco enderecoDeEntrega;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.pedido")
    private Set<ItemPedido> itens = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I also have a POST method to add the Object:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@Valid @RequestBody Pedido obj) {
    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(pedidoService.insert(obj).getId()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
}
```

My POST request stays like this:

```
{
   "cliente":{
      "id":1
   },
   "enderecoDeEntrega":{
      "id":1
   },
   "pagamento":{
      "numeroDeParcelas":10,
      "@type":"pagamentoComCartao"
   },
   "itens":[
      {
         "quantidade":2,
         "produto":{
            "id":1
         }
      },
     {
         "quantidade":2,
         "produto":{
            "id":3
         }
      },
      {
         "quantidade":1,
         "produto":{
            "id":2
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem is that when the request arrives from the server side, HashSet arrives with only one item, even if I send several items.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Let me guess: you implemented hashCode() and equals() in ItemPedido, based on the ID.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!!!!